# @SerializedName and @ColumnInfo annotations conflict during Room database migration?

Tags: android, android-room, database-migration

I am finding that the provided field names in annotations @SerializedName and @ColumnInfo must match when doing a room database migration, for both auto- and manual- migrations. Is this true or am I missing something?

For the sake of the code I am showing a AutoMigration, but I set it up as a manual migration as well and received the same issue.

**Database Setup.**

```
@Database(
    version = 30,
    entities = [
        ...
        MobileService::class,
        ...
    ],
    exportSchema = true,
    autoMigrations = [
        AutoMigration(from = 29, to = 30)
     ]
)
```

**Entity class.**

Note the difference between the field names provided in @SerializedName vs. @ColumnInfo for the new column I'm trying to add. The data will be coming down from an API call, so I want the SerializedName to be "scac" so that it's properly mapped when reading the incoming json. I was hoping for @ColumnInfo to be "primary_scac", since we'll have another table with a field "scac".

```
@Entity(tableName = "mobile_service")
data class MobileService(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    @SerializedName("id")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Int = 0,

    ...

    @SerializedName("legal_terms_name")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "legal_terms_name")
    val legalTermsName: String? = null,

    // NEW COLUMN ADDED HERE
    @SerializedName("scac")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "parent_scac")
    val parentScac: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("dr_contact_email")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "dr_contact_email")
    val drContactEmail: String? = null,

    ...
)
```

Attempting to do the migration from 29 to 30 yields a stack trace. Here's a snippet of it below. Feel free to look through it, but from what I am seeing the new column information is found in the "Expected" TableInfo, while it does not exist in the "Found".

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle:  mobile_service(com.tms.android.data.ms.MobileService). 

Expected: 2023-02-22 11:23:27.337 17960-17960 AndroidRuntime          com.tms.android.appname       E  TableInfo{name='mobile_service', columns={legal_terms_name=Column{name='legal_terms_name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, driver_arrived_flag=Column{name='driver_arrived_flag', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, ping_equip_issues=Column{name='ping_equip_issues', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, apns_password=Column{name='apns_password', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, enable_location_rating=Column{name='enable_location_rating', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, max_search=Column{name='max_search', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, ping_birthday=Column{name='ping_birthday', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, dr_email_list=Column{name='dr_email_list', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, allow_time_off_feature=Column{name='allow_time_off_feature', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, mobile_branding_id=Column{name='mobile_branding_id', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, dr_contact_phone=Column{name='dr_contact_phone', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, require_order_term=Column{name='require_order_term', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, dr_contact_name=Column{name='dr_contact_name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, ping_hiredate=Column{name='ping_hiredate', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, qualcom_enable=Column{name='qualcom_enable', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, ping_physical_expire=Column{name='ping_physical_expire', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, use_relay=Column{name='use_relay', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, enable_raterequest=Column{name='enable_raterequest', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, allow_driver_password_reset=Column{name='allow_driver_password_reset', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, parent_scac=Column{name='parent_scac', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, login_expire=Column{name='login_expire', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, gcm_sender_key=Column{name='gcm_sender_key', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, allow_geotab_sso=Column{name='allow_geotab_sso', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, ping_mvr_expire=Column{name='ping_mvr_expire', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, enable_bol_prompt=Column{name='enable_bol_prompt', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, driver_settlement_flag=Column{name='driver_settlement_flag', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, dr_response=Column{name='dr_response', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, require_legal_term=Column{name='require_legal_term', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, time_off_event_code=Column{name='time_off_event_code', type='TEXT', affinity='2', no 2023-02-22 11:23:27.337 17960-17960 AndroidRuntime          com.tms.android.appname       E  tNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, allow_driver_rec=Column{name='allow_driver_rec', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, ping_license_expire=Column{name='ping_license_expire', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, proof_of_delivery=Column{name='proof_of_delivery', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, allow_driver_history_report=Column{name='allow_driver_history_report', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, dr_contact_email=Column{name='dr_contact_email', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, allow_driver_dlvr_receipts=Column{name='allow_driver_dlvr_receipts', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]} 

Found: 2023-02-22 11:23:27.338 17960-17960 AndroidRuntime          com.tms.android.appname       E  TableInfo{name='mobile_service', columns={legal_terms_name=Column{name='legal_terms_name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, driver_arrived_flag=Column{name='driver_arrived_flag', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, ping_equip_issues=Column{name='ping_equip_issues', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, apns_password=Column{name='apns_password', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, enable_location_rating=Column{name='enable_location_rating', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, max_search=Column{name='max_search', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, ping_birthday=Column{name='ping_birthday', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, dr_email_list=Column{name='dr_email_list', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, allow_time_off_feature=Column{name='allow_time_off_feature', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, mobile_branding_id=Column{name='mobile_branding_id', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, dr_contact_phone=Column{name='dr_contact_phone', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, require_order_term=Column{name='require_order_term', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, dr_contact_name=Column{name='dr_contact_name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, ping_hiredate=Column{name='ping_hiredate', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, qualcom_enable=Column{name='qualcom_enable', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, ping_physical_expire=Column{name='ping_physical_expire', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, use_relay=Column{name='use_relay', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, enable_raterequest=Column{name='enable_raterequest', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, allow_driver_password_reset=Column{name='allow_driver_password_reset', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, login_expire=Column{name='login_expire', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, gcm_sender_key=Column{name='gcm_sender_key', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, allow_geotab_sso=Column{name='allow_geotab_sso', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, ping_mvr_expire=Column{name='ping_mvr_expire', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, enable_bol_prompt=Column{name='enable_bol_prompt', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, driver_settlement_flag=Column{name='driver_settlement_flag', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, dr_response=Column{name='dr_response', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, require_legal_term=Column{name='require_legal_term', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, time_off_event_code=Column{name='time_off_event_code', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, allow_driver_rec=Column{name='allow_driver_rec', type='TEXT', affini 2023-02-22 11:23:27.338 17960-17960 AndroidRuntime          com.tms.android.appname       E  ty='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, ping_license_expire=Column{name='ping_license_expire', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, proof_of_delivery=Column{name='proof_of_delivery', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, allow_driver_history_report=Column{name='allow_driver_history_report', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, dr_contact_email=Column{name='dr_contact_email', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, allow_driver_dlvr_receipts=Column{name='allow_driver_dlvr_receipts', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]} 

at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(RoomOpenHelper.java:103) at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onUpgrade(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:183) 
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:416) 
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:316) 
at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:151) 
at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:112) 
at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:706) 
at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:483) 
at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:526) 
at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.java:86) at com.tms.android.data.settings.SettingsDao_Impl$7.call(SettingsDao_Impl.java:201) 
at com.tms.android.data.settings.SettingsDao_Impl$7.call(SettingsDao_Impl.java:198) 
at androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom$Companion$execute$4$job$1.invokeSuspend(CoroutinesRoom.kt:88) 
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33) 
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

Making the field names match across the SerializedName and ColumnInfo annotations result in the expected migration running successfully.

```
    @SerializedName("scac")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "scac")
    val parentScac: String? = null,
```

I'm trying to understand why this is the case, for the sake of knowing about the "gotchas" with room migration. Our app hasn't had the need to do any migrations yet, since we're aren't yet on the store right now. We've been happily destructive migrating for quite some time, and now it's time to start keeping track of the changes and not erasing the entire DB for simple reasons.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to understand why this is the case, for the sake of knowing about the "gotchas" with room migration.

At one time I was developing a conversion App to do exactly that. However, when I found it needless I discontinued. In short there is little need to know as Room provides the answer.

- It was beginning to become a nightmare as changes were made
- In answer to the question, well broadly, it's the complexity of the annotation processors that determine the column names (types and NOT NULL constraints) to be used for the table and also for creating the returned objects where field/member names have to be associated with the column name. In short it's quite complex that has to be undertaken and will probably always have *gotcha*'s.

All you need to do is

1. introduce the changes to the `@Entity` annotated classes,
2. ensure they are part of the `@Database`'s entities paremeter
3. compile the project (obviously repeating 1-3 until successful compile)

   1. I would suggest also a warning free build
4. locate the **`java (generated)`** (visible when using the Android View) e.g.:-

   1. [image]
5. Find the class/file that is the same as the `@Database` annotated class but **suffixed with _Impl**.
6. Find the method call **`createAllTables`**
7. The SQL is the ***'EXPECTED'*** i.e. with all of the nuances that Room introduces.

   1. by ***'EXPECTED'*** as per `Expected: 2023-02-22 11:23:27.337 17960-17960 AndroidRuntime ....`
   2. this SQL can be used for the basis of the migration

      1. The migration (conversion) could be done in a Migration and would basically consist of `ALTER`ing. However, the limitations of `ALTER` may require that the existing tables be renamed, the new/converted tables being created using the SQL from the generated java and then the new tables being populated by copying the data from the renamed original tables. An example of undertaking this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68183015/android-room-migrate-from-sqliteopenhelper/68185566#68185566)  (plenty more examples if you search SO using `user:4744514 [android-room] migrate`)